# Installing Midnight Commander from sources (no root privileges)

Tags: linux, installation, suse, midnight-commander

I tried to configure 
./configure --prefix=/localfolder
glib-2.26.1/
make
make install

but it fails at make stage.

trying to configure
mc-4.6.1/
and make doesn't obviously work.

What are the steps I need to make in order to install midnight comander for my local user in a custom folder?

Make for glib gives me these errors

```
/usr/bin/msgfmt: found 2 fatal errors
cp: cannot stat `test.mo': No such file or directory
gmake[4]: *** [test.mo] Error 1
gmake[4]: Leaving directory `/remote/folder/mc/glib-2.26.1/gio/tests'
gmake[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
gmake[3]: Leaving directory `/remote/folder/mc/glib-2.26.1/gio'
gmake[2]: *** [all] Error 2
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/remote/folder/mc/glib-2.26.1/gio'
gmake[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/remote/folder/mc/glib-2.26.1'
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

./configure --prefix=**/localfolder**

This will install to a folder underneath the root directory, which is not writable for a normal user.

This is the correct commandline:

`./configure --prefix=~/localfolder && make && make install`

(Of course, I'm assuming that you don't have write priveliges to /localfolder. The missing file *test.mo* may be another problem entirely.)