# Tricky Matlab remote installation on Linux server from Windows

Tags: linux, ssh, installation, remote-desktop, matlab

I need to install Matlab on Linux server. 
Here are the constrains:

- I have only remote access to that server via SSH from machine running Windows (using putty).
- There is no X server installed on that server but I'm still able to run Java applications in visual mode using Xming
- I have no root access on the server

Matlab is given as an ISO file and license file. I have both of them on the server in directory `/tmp/matlab_install`.

I guess all I need to do is to do is:

1. mount that ISO somehow
2. run installation
3. hope that the installation will need no root privileges and that the installation itself will either need no Xserver or will run on Java

The question is how do I do the first step with no root privileges?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/180744/how-do-i-extract-an-iso-on-linux-without-root-access

Comment: @Ярослав Рахматуллин before posting I have done a lot of google searching. That particular one that you suggest does not bring any new information

Answer (score 1):

If [midnight commander](https://www.midnight-commander.org/) is installed you can [copy the iso's contents using that](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/how-to-mount-view-iso-file-as-root-and-non-root-user-in-unix/) and run the installation from your copy.

If it is not installed, see [here](https://superuser.com/a/225092/151431) for help on how to install mc from source using the `--prefix` option of its `configure` script.

Comment: Fortunately it is installed. But when I try to open that iso using `mc` I get this error message: `/usr/share/mc/extfs/iso9660: line 26: isoinfo: command not found`. It looks like `isoinfo` is not installed. I have created new question on how to install it [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51806/how-to-remotelly-install-isoinfo-on-red-hat-linux).